# CakePHP theme is not working on live server

Tags: cakephp

I created a website using CakePHP. Here: http://www.aaryanahmed.net/

I used cakephp theme. Theme path is app/view/Theme/orange. It workes fine in my localhost but now working when I uploaded it by Cpanel.

In AppController I introduced the theme in this way

```
public function beforeRender() {
if (
        $this->params['action'] == 'index'
        || $this->params['action'] == 'edit'
        || $this->params['action'] == 'add' && $this->params['controller'] != 'contacts'
        || $this->params['action'] == 'delete'
        || $this->here != 'http://www.aaryanahmed.net/'
    ) 
    {
        $this->theme = null;
    }

else if($this->params['plugin'] == 'usermgmt')
    {
        $this->theme = '';
        $this->layout = 'usermgmt';
    }
else {$this->view = "Theme";
    $this->theme = 'orange';
}
```

}

Theme is not working even if I use $this->theme = 'orange'; in AppController
My htaccess file is lihe that

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your developing computer windows and the server linux? Then it can be a problem of not following [conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html) and/or naming [folders](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-folder-structure.html) other than what is expected from the framework. In unix systems `Test` is different from `test`. Windows treats them the same.

For example you mention `app/view/Theme/orange` which should be `app/View/Theme/Orange`. The documentation says explicitly that [it's important to remember that CakePHP expects CamelCase theme names](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/themes.html).

Also consider that your code doesn't follow [cake's coding standards](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/contributing/cakephp-coding-conventions.html) either. Although those guidelines are for the framework it helps maintain a common presentation for all cakephp code presented here.

Comment: I fixed by using $this->theme = 'orange'; in every action. But with my previous logic I made some large application. But now when I am using Cake 2.3.9 I faced the problem.

Comment: Well you kind of circumvented the problem instead of fixing it, which means it may come back to haunt you later in the future. But it's your code so if you're happy with the solution it's enough.

Comment: Thank you. I have got that my code is wrong. Never I used this code. Now I know the convention. Your ans helped me. Thanks again.